# How to loop through a range of week status variables in SAS and pull status according to specific week given by other variable

Tags: loops, sas

I have a range of weekly variables describing a person's "status" (from week 1, 2010 to 2012 week 17).

The variables are given by:

```
y_1001, y_1002,...y1052, y1101, y1102,......y_1217
```

I define the period of variables like this:

```
%let period = y_1001-1052 y_1101-y1148;
```

I also have a treatment period given as a start date and an end date. My challenge is to find the status given by the y_ variables **in the week after the person stops the treatment**.

I am not too familiar with SAS, but my idea was to "pick" the correct y_ variable based on a week counter, say by counting the number of weeks since the beginning of the period  (week 1 in 2010) and until the date where the treatment ends.

I get the weeks until end of treatment like this

```
week_count = 1 + intck( 'week.2', '1JAN2010'd, end_treatment_date, 'd');
```

**But how can I retrieve the corresponding y_ variable based on this count?**

After fruitless search on how to loop over the period variables and pick the number corresponding to the week_count variable for each person, I thought about going a different way... say something like this.

```
array weeks(*) &period;
do i = 1 to dim(weeks) by 1;
  if week_count = i then end_status = y_10&i;
end
```

...but with modifications to take into account that there is a mismatch between the dimension of the array and the number of weeks and years.

But then my challenge is to make the following part work...

```
if week_count = i then end_status = y_10&i;
```

How can I make SAS pick the right y_ variable based on the loop index? This seems like a really simple problem, but somehow I have not managed to find a solution. Is there no way to use the variable "i" as input in defining the correct y_ variable?

Would really appreciate if somebody could throw some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
if week_count = i then end_status = weeks{i};
```

Comment: Aargh yes, you are right! Now I feel like deleting my question :)

Comment: Don't worry.  Almost everything I have ever learned has been from making mistakes like this.  I'll bet you never do it again!

Answer (score 0):

VVALUEX is a little known function in SAS which can help you to extract a value from a SAS variable name. Here your problem is to construct the SAS variable name given the number of weeks from the 1st Jan to the end of treatment. You can avoid using a DO LOOP for every observation by using the ideas in the example below -

```
data _null_;
    end_treatment_date = "09FEB2010"d;
    y_1007 = 'D';
    status = vvaluex(compress("y_" || substr(strip(year(end_treatment_date)), 3, 2) || put(1 + intck("week.2", "01JAN2010"d, end_treatment_date), z2.)));
    put status;
run;
```

The variable name is constructed as follows - initally you take the string "y_" and then append the last two digits of the year followed by the week using similar logic to your variable week_count as before. You get the variable you want, and then apply VVALUEX to get the value. Running the DO LOOP for every observation can be inefficient if you have millions of them.